# Update data of model relationships when using foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, laravel-7, laravel-controller

I am a newbie in Laravel, and I'm trying to use a `foreach` loop with `updateOrCreate()` in the update function. However, it doesn't work, and there is no error. I have the following three models.

**Sales Team**

```php
class SalesTeam extends Model
{
    public function salesTeamLeaders()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(SalesTeamleader::class);
    }

    public function salesTeamMember()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(SalesTeamMember::class);
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
}
```

**Sales Team Leader**

```php
class SalesTeamLeader extends Model
{
    public function salesTeam()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SalesTeam::class);
    }
}
```

**Sales Team Member**

```php
class SalesTeamMember extends Model
{
    public function salesTeam()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SalesTeam::class);
    }
}
```

**SalesTeam Controller**

```php
class SalesTeamController extends Controller
{
    // Update
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'description' => '',
        ]);

        $salesteam = SalesTeam::find($id);
        $salesteam->name = $request->name;
        $salesteam->description = $request->description;
        $salesteam->save();

        foreach ($request['leaders'] as $leader) {
            SalesTeamLeader::updateOrCreate([
                'salesteam_id' => $salesteam->id,
                'leader_id' => $leader
            ]);
        }


        foreach ($request['members'] as $member) {
            SalesTeamMember::updateOrCreate([
                'salesteam_id' => $salesteam->id,
                'member_id' => $member
            ]);
        }

        // Flash Message
        Session()->flash("success", "ปรับปรุงข้อมูลเรียบร้อยแล้ว!");
        
        return redirect('/admin/salesTeamDashboard');
    }
}
```

Comment: What you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Comment: why `updateOrInsert`? it looks like you need to be syncing relationships

Comment: The foreach loop that I trying to use to update the relationship data.

Comment: are these actually `belongsToMany` relationships with pivot tables?

Comment: I don't know that much but yeah, I think they are pivot tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you just need to sync a list of leader and members for the sales team. Assuming the relationships setup in the `SalesTeam` model are correct you can use the `sync` method of the `BelongsToMany` to do this:

```
$salesteam->salesTeamLeaders()->sync($request->input('leaders', []));

$salesteam->salesTeamMember()->sync($request->input('members', []));
```

Though `salesTeamMember` should be named in the plural.

Comment: I got this  message
 
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'whoservice.sales_team_sales_team_leader' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `sales_team_sales_team_leader` where `sales_team_id` = 4)

Comment: yea the relationships aren't setup correctly ... do you have a `leaders` and `members` table?

Comment: I have both of them, sir. I named them salesteam_leaders and salesteam_members

Comment: do you have a table connecting `sales_team` and `salesteam_leaders`?

Comment: In SalesTeam Tables. I have 2 fields that are salsteam_id and leader_id.

Answer (score 0):

First, return simple response to ensure you are getting correct **request** data and the **id**. You can replace **$request['leaders']** to **$request->input('leaders')** and **$request['members']** to **$request->input('members')**. You should not put the query builder in the for each loop. Instead process it at first then pass the whole array to update. As query takes some time to run, your for loop may end by this time and go out of scope.

```
return response()->json([
    'request_data' => $request,
    'id' => $id,
]);
```